$\phi_{\sigma} (x) = O(|x|^{−α})$, as $x→ ±∞$.
I am currently studying a paper published in the "Journal of Approximation Theory" on Neural Networks. We have the following definitions:
Definition(Sigmoidal functions):A function $\sigma:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be sigmoidal function if it satisfies $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} σ(x) = 0 ~\text{and}~
\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} σ(x) = 1.$$
Further, we consider a sigmoidal function that is non-decreasing and satisfying three conditions:
$$~(S1)~ σ(x) − 1/2~ \text{is an odd function};\\
(S2)~ σ ∈ C^2(\mathbb{R})~ \text{is concave for}~ x ≥ 0;\\
(S3)~ σ(x) = O(|x|^{−α}) ~\text{as}~ x → −∞,~\text{ for some}~ α > 1,$$
Defintion($\phi_{\sigma}$):Now we define the kernal function $\phi_{\sigma}$ as follows:
$\phi_{\sigma} :=1/2
[σ(x + 1) − σ(x − 1)],~ x ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
Now i have to prove the following lemma:

Lemma 2.2. Let $\sigma$ be as sigmoidal function as in the Definition above, and let $\alpha$ be as in condition (S3). Then

(i) $\phi_{\sigma} (x) ≥ 0$ for every $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, with $\phi_{\sigma}(1) > 0$, and moreover $\lim_{
x→±∞}
\phi_{\sigma}(x) = 0;$
(ii) The function $\phi_{\sigma}(x)$ is even;
(iii) The function $\phi_{\sigma} (x)$:
is non-decreasing for $x < 0$ and non-increasing for $x ≥ 0$;
(iv) $\phi_{\sigma} (x) = O(|x|^{−α})$, as $x→ ±∞$.

Furthermore, $\phi_{\sigma} ∈ L^1(R)$;

(v) For every $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$,
$\sum_{
k∈\mathbb{Z}}
\phi_\sigma(x − k) = 1,$
and
$∥\phi_{\sigma} ∥_1 =
\int_{\mathbb{R}}
\phi_{\sigma} (x) dx =
1$


In part (iv) we need to take help of condition (S3), i found its proof in some other paper but not satisfied with the way they have proved,the proof is as follows:
"Proof. By assumption (S3), there exist $C>0,M > 0$ such that
$σ(x) ≤ C|x|^{−α}$, for every $x < −M$, for some given $α > 0$. Then,
$\phi_σ (x) ≤ σ(x + 1) ≤ C |x|^{−α}$,
for every $x < −M − 1$. Moreover, using assumptions (S1) and
(S3), we have for every $x > M + 1$
$\phi_σ (x) ≤ 1 − σ(x − 1) = σ(1 − x) ≤ C |x|^{−α}$,
and then the proof follows."
My Doubt:
What I don't understand here is:
Knowing $σ(x) ≤ C|x|^{−α}$, for every $x < −M$, for some given $α > 0$,Then,
$\phi_σ (x) ≤ σ(x + 1) ≤ C |x|^{−α}$,
for every $x < −M − 1$
while i think it should be like ;
$σ(x) ≤ C|x|^{−α}$, for every $x < −M$, for some given $α > 0$. Then,
$\phi_σ (x) ≤ σ(x + 1) ≤ C |x+1|^{−α}$,
for every $x < −M − 1$
How author has directly use $|x|^{−α}$ while if we change the input x to x+1 then it should be changed both sides.
similarly for the case of $\sigma(1-x)$ he has used same logic i.e., "we have for every $x > M + 1$
$\phi_σ (x) ≤ 1 − σ(x − 1) = σ(1 − x) ≤ C |x|^{−α}$, while  it should be like "$σ(1 − x) ≤ C |1-x|^{−α}$
please help me to understand this doubt.
Thanks!!

They just throw away the $\pm1$ because it does not really matter. You are interested in the asymptotic behavior after all

could you please elaborate it mathematically, as i just wrote there in my question post?

It's an easy exercise, try doing it :). A hint is: you can choose $C$ "as you like", so you can take advantage of this.  I mean that If instead of $C$ you prove the inequalities with, say,  $2C$ it is still fine.

with humble request, i request you to explain a little bit more, please.

You just need to estimate $|x+1|^{- \alpha}$ with $C' |x|^{- \alpha}$ for some $C'>0$ when $|x|>M$

ok, thanks got it
